# Merge/Include layout view is not visible

Tags: android, android-layout

Blue outline that should be outlining elements in layout editor shows **only a blue dot in the top left corner when using include, to include layouts that have merge tag** at their root (example with the picture below).

I have tried assigning layout_width/height to include a tag with no success.

When including layouts that have a concrete layout at their root (ex. LinearLayout), blue outline shows properly.

```
// el_close.xml
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="36dp"
        android:layout_height="36dp"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:foreground="@drawable/ic_close_small" />
</merge>
```

```
// main_layout.xml
...
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingHorizontal="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="28dp">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/close"
        layout="@layout/el_close" />
...
</LinearLayout>
```

[image showing include/merge outline in top-left corner](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wu0di.png)

Comment: Just remove the merge tag in el_close.xml, you don't even need it.

Comment: @iCantC Thank you! That solves the problem.